# How to initialize a JSON member with indented JSON?

Tags: json, angular, typescript

Here, variable `some` is initialized with a JSON string
that I need expanded and thus **indented** for readability.

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
      some:any = JSON.parse('[{"id":"EN","fill":"blue","classb":"FR someclass"},{"id":"US","fill":"hsl(240, 100%, 35%)","classb":"someclass"},{"id":"ES","fill":"hsl(240, 100%, 60%)","classb":"someclass"},{"id":"IT","fill":"hsl(240, 100%, 90%)","classb":"someclass"}]');

      getStyle(zoneId:string):String{
        var test = this.some.find(x => x.id === zoneId);
        if( test === undefined) return "#000000";
        if( test.fill != undefined) return test.fill;
           return "red";
      }
}
```

How would it be possible to work with indented JSON to initialize TypeScript/Angular class members?

Comment: other than just writing it? make it a const outside the class or in a config file

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: @Aluan Haddad for readability like said in the question ...

Comment: @user1767316 JSON **_is_** JavaScript why not use an object? E.g. `some = {"id":"EN","fill":"blue"};`. Why use a string? If you do what I suggest you not only be able to format flexibly but also will automatically gain language support, validation, and intellisense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a [template string](https://jack.ofspades.com/multiline-strings-in-es6-javascript/index.html) with backticks, which allow newlines for your formatted JSON string:

```
class MyComponent {
  some = JSON.parse(`
    [
      {
        "id": "EN",
        "fill": "blue",
        "classb": "FR someclass"
      },
      {
        "id": "US",
        "fill": "hsl(240, 100%, 35%)",
        "classb": "someclass"
      },
      {
        "id": "ES",
        "fill": "hsl(240, 100%, 60%)",
        "classb": "someclass"
      },
      {
        "id": "IT",
        "fill": "hsl(240, 100%, 90%)",
        "classb": "someclass"
      }
    ]
    `);
}
```

Comment: Why would you write that instead of `some = [{id: "EN", ...];`?

Comment: That's a question for the OP.

Answer (score 1):

Just use an Object. JSON is actually part of JavaScript (for all intents and purposes).

You do not need an embedded string at all.

For example, you can write the following

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
  some = [ // note removed `: any` as it degrades tooling esp when there is an initializer
    {"id": "EN", "fill": "blue", "classb": "FR someclass"},
    {"id": "US", "fill": "hsl(240, 100%, 35%)", "classb": "someclass"},
    {"id": "ES", "fill": "hsl(240, 100%, 60%)", "classb": "someclass"},
    {"id": "IT", "fill": "hsl(240, 100%, 90%)", "classb": "someclass"}
  ];

  getStyle(zoneId: string): string { // note correct type is `string` not `String`
    var test = this.some.find(x => x.id === zoneId);
    if (test === undefined) return "#000000";
    if (test.fill != undefined) return test.fill;
    return "red";
  }
}
```

This grants full tooling and language level support while allowing for expressive formatting with all the possibilities allowed for by JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks  @Aluan Haddad. You answerd in addition to your comment that I could test in the meanwhile. I leave the right answer check to tony19 who found the solution to my initial effective question.